# Using regex (Regular Expressions) in Parenscript

Tags: regex, lisp, common-lisp, parenscript

I am trying out Parenscript. While trying to experiment with regex function, I get unexpected output. for example, the [reference manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/reference.html) shows:

```
(regex "foobar")
    /foobar/;

(regex "/foobar/i")
    /foobar/i;
```

However in my repl I get error that function (parenscript:regex..) is undefined.

```
The function parenscript:regex is undefined.
   [Condition of type undefined-function]

Restarts:
 0: [continue] Retry using regex.
 1: [use-value] Use specified function
 2: [retry] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 3: [*abort] Return to SLIME's top level.
 4: [abort] abort thread (#<thread "repl-thread" running {1002319B63}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (sb-impl::retry-%coerce-name-to-fun regex nil)
  1: (sb-int:simple-eval-in-lexenv (regex "foobar") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (eval (regex "foobar"))
 --more--
```

I tried changing namespace to cl-user,ps, etc, nothing worked. OTOH, just for checking, I tried using functions sin, random, etc., and that worked. I mean, typing (sin 0.1) in repl yielded expected output.

Any help will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

In a SBCL read-eval-print-loop:

```
CL-USER> (in-package "PS")
#<PACKAGE "PARENSCRIPT">

PS> (ps (regex "foobar"))
"/foobar/;"

PS> (in-package "CL-USER")
#<package "COMMON-LISP-USER">

cl-user> (ps:ps (ps:regex "foobar"))
"/foobar/;"
```

`PS:PS` is the Parenscript compiler as a macro operator.

Comment: Thank You [Rainer Joswig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69545/rainer-joswig) so much. I was missing the ps:regex within the second bracket. I have another question in continuation. If I do (random 30) in PS> it results in a random integer below 30. But (ps:ps (ps:random 30)) yields javascript code, not the random number. Is there a way to understand underlying consistency/theme? I will be trying to use it for form validation in html forms. Thank you again.

Comment: I think I made my comment convoluted. Attempting to simplify. In PS> (random 30) -> integer below 30. (regex "foobar") throws error. (ps (regex "foobar")) -> "/foobar/;" In cl-user> (ps:ps (ps:regex "foobar")) -> "/foobar/;". (ps:ps (ps:random 30)) -> javascript code, not an integer below 30. Is there a way to understand what to expect? Function sine works like random. Gives numerical result only in PS>, js-code in cl-user>. Sine behaves like random. regex seems differently behaved.

Comment: Further, could you similarly show by example how the regex with cl-interpol is to be used? After doing (ql:quickload :cl-interpol) and getting into PS> I did (ps (regex #?r"/([^\s]+)foobar/i")) and it throws an error. no dispatch function defined for #\? Thank you in advance. And apologies for pestering you with so many questions.

Comment: you understand what Parenscript is and what PS:PS does?

Comment: As per my understanding (correct me if I am missing something): Parenscript coverts CL like statements ( a subset, and some additions for browser commands like Window, document etc) into javascript. From within "PS" package we can use plain ps, and from outside (if we haven't imported/used it) we need ps:ps. So my confusion was/is why, within PS> namespace (random 30) and (sin 0.1) were evaluating to values, but (regex ...) was not. While (ps (regex ..)), (ps (random ..)), and (ps (sin ..)) etc were (rightly) converting to javascript.

Comment: @polymath: `regex` has no meaning in Common Lisp. It is a functionality in Parenscript and thus only can be used in Parenscript code.

Comment: @RJ: Thanks!! That clears my doubt. Thanks so much.